# add/ sub offset time to existing trigger

Tags: cron, quartz-scheduler

I would like to update a trigger created in quartz with an offset. For example, if I create a trigger at 10.00 I would like to add/sub 2 hours to it so it would fire at 08.00 instead.

My question is if it is possible to add/sub time(min/hour/days/years) to an existing trigger when it should fire?
If no, any ideas of how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
// get a TriggerBuilder that builds the old trigger configuration
TriggerBuilder tb = oldTrigger.getTriggerBuilder();

// set the new start time based on the old start time
long newStart = oldTrigger.getStartTime() - 2*60*60*1000;
tb.startAt(newStart);

// create the new trigger
Trigger newTrigger = tb.build();

// replace the old trigger with the new one.
scheduler.rescheduleJob(oldTrigger.getKey(), newTrigger);
```